Concat 2-3 columns in Google Database
I'm using Google App Sheet.
How can I join columns using this concat or textjoin expression under "Name" Column?
Not using Spreadsheet, I'm using database.
Not able to find the solution. I have attached the image for clear understanding.
Reference image
Red Line columns to be joined in Blue line column.

Don't try and create it in the database (or spreadsheet), instead create it in the app's data section by adding a new virtual column with the formula:
CONCATENATE([Brand], " ", [RAM Memory], " ", [RAM Memory Speed (MHz)])

